# Google Suite data access by administrator

Tags: gmail, google-drive, privacy, google-workspace-for-business

I have a custom domain e-mail from my university an they are using Google Suite (Gmail, Drive, etc). I was reading this page https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/181692

Does this means that the administrator can access all my e-mails and google drive files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer

Yes

## Source

From https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/181692

> It’s important to note that your administrator has access to any data you store in this account, including your email.